# Heroku + docker + nginx every request returns 500

Tags: nginx, heroku

I deploy my docker container to Heroku hosting. Container contains nginx and static files, created by webpack on contained-build stage. 
root directory is /data/www with index.html, style.css, style.css.map, bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js and directories with assets(images/ etc)

my nginx conf:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    server {
        include listen.conf;

        types{
            text/javascript   js;
            text/css          css;
            image/jpeg        jpg;
            image/png         png;
        }
        default_type text/html;

        root /data/www;
        index /index.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

it works locally, but when I push image to Heroku:

```
docker build -t registry.heroku.com/tp-frontend-kv/web .
docker push registry.heroku.com/tp-frontend-kv/web
```

Every request returns 500, nginx log on Heroku :

```
2017-05-21T10:31:09.254234+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tp-frontend-kv.herokuapp.com request_id=63388b37-4b9b-432b-88c2-8ae393e2708d fwd="178.22.54.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=500 bytes=355 protocol=https

2017-05-21T10:31:09.256223+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017/05/21 10:31:09 [error] 14#14: *4 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 10.84.188.241, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "tp-frontend-kv.herokuapp.com", referrer: "https://dashboard.heroku.com/"

2017-05-21T10:31:09.256368+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.84.188.241 - - [21/May/2017:10:31:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 193 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"

2017-05-21T10:31:14.935539+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017/05/21 10:31:14 [error] 13#13: *5 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 10.84.188.241, server: , request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "tp-frontend-kv.herokuapp.com"

2017-05-21T10:31:14.935653+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.84.188.241 - - [21/May/2017:10:31:14 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 500 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"

2017-05-21T10:31:14.934805+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/index.html" host=tp-frontend-kv.herokuapp.com request_id=c7a3943b-3714-4745-8758-37002e735d6e fwd="178.22.54.74" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=355 protocol=https
```

What could be the problem?

PS dockerfile and others : [github](https://github.com/frontend-park-mail-ru/2017_1_KV-Team/tree/dev)

Answer (score 1):

Before deployment, keep an eye on your logs by running (heroku cli required):

```
$ heroku logs --app <your-app> -t
```

You may see an nginx startup error which is causing the 500 responses, for example, if its trying to bind to port 80 (default) you will see this:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Keep an eye on these errors, it should provide some insight.